# MySql : order by in group by takes no effect

Tags: mysql

I have an table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id`  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`sale_date`  date NOT NULL ,
`store_id`  varchar(64) NOT NULL ,
`money`  decimal(10,2) NOT NULL ,
`type`  tinyint(4) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

and I insert the data as below:

```
2020-03-12 111 500 1
2020-03-12 111 800 2
2020-03-12 222 900 2
```

I want to group by sale_date and store_id，and inner group order by type desc, my sql is like this:

```
select * from(
select * from test order by type desc) r group by sale_date, store_id;
```

but the result is:

```
2020-03-12 111 500 1
2020-03-12 222 900 2
```

and the result is supposed to be like this:

```
2020-03-12 111 800 2
2020-03-12 222 900 2
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)
and if you want to broaden the appeal of the question to this community (by one, anyway), then consider removing the word 'wanna' from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.* 
from test t
where t.type = (select max(type) from test where sale_date = t.sale_date and store_id = t.store_id)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nACiUrth7nKVHhvSJrKGDD/0).
Results:

```
| id  | sale_date  | store_id | money | type |
| --- | ---------- | -------- | ----- | ---- |
| 2   | 2020-03-12 | 111      | 800   | 2    |
| 3   | 2020-03-12 | 222      | 900   | 2    |
```